# Verify token with API in Angular8 canActivate method of AuthGuard

Tags: javascript, angular, async-await, es6-promise, auth-guard

I want to do some validation on each refresh request for some routes. So I'm using Angular `AuthGuard`. The problem is in `canActivate` method I want to perform validation with online API.

API is `/token/verify` which simply gets `token` variable (jwt) and verify if it's true or false.
Then if verify is not complete will route to `/login` page else do the rest.

Here is the code:

```
canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
let token = this.auth.getToken();
let url = '/token/verify/';
if (!token) {
  this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  return false;
}
this.auth.verifyToken().then(res => {
  return true;
}).catch(err => {
  this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  return false;
})
```

and the `verifyToken` method is like this:

```
verifyToken(): Promise<boolean> {
    let token = this.getToken();
    return !token ?
        new Promise<boolean>(resolve => {
            resolve(false);
            return false;
        }) :
        this.http.post(this.url + '/token/verify/', { 'token': token })
            .toPromise()
            .then((res) => {
                localStorage.data = JSON.stringify(res);//(res.json());
                return true;
            }
            ).catch((error) => {
                return false
            });
}
```

**Problem** is that the `promise` call doesn't work and will be passed. I mean the first part that does check it from localstorage works fine. But the next part that checks it with online API will not work. and `authGuard` doesn't wait for its response to do the routing.

I guess it should be in some `async/await` manner. But I did some tests and none of them worked. Will be glad if anyone could help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll be able to simplify the whole implementation if you use `Observable`s instead.

If you do consider that proposal, then your `verifyToken` method could be refactored to this:

```
import { of, Observable } from 'rxjs';

verifyToken(): Observable<boolean> {
  const token = this.getToken();
  return token ? this.http
    .post(this.url + '/token/verify/', {
      'token': token
    })
    .pipe(
      tap(res => localStorage.data = JSON.stringify(res)),
      map(
        res => true,
        error => false
      )
    ) : of(false)
}
```

And then in your Guard, you'd simply do this:

```
canActivate(
  next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot
): Observable < boolean > | Promise < boolean > | boolean {
  const token = this.auth.getToken();
  const url = "/token/verify/";

  if (!token) {
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
  }

  return this.auth.verifyToken().pipe(
    catchError(err => {
      console.log('Handling error locally and rethrowing it...', err);
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      return of(false);
    })
  );

}
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-auth-guard-example-stack-overflow) for your ref.

Comment: appreciate for spending time to write a detailed response. But can you check the canActivate last `return` statement. It seem some change needed for it. It gives this error `Argument type MonoTypeOperatorFunction<unknown> is not assignable...` Can u check it again plz.

Comment: @RezaTorkamanAhmadi, please try the updated answer. I've placed the `if` condition in `{}`

Comment: No, still the same error. Shouldn't i use `pipe` and `catch` methods instead?

Comment: @RezaTorkamanAhmadi, sorry about that. I've updated my answer with the correct code and a Sample Working Demo for your ref. Please check if that helps.

Comment: I was able to make it work with `catchError` Also. Please verify my changes too.
really appreciate it. with your help i was able to solve it. :)