# How to access protected routes / disable Auth Guard by knowing auth status

Tags: javascript, angular, authentication, angular-routing

**scenario** :
Here  i am building an application in which currently i have a page called *products-info* where a url is sent to the customer and on clicking on the link he can directly open that particular product page and see the info and the same page will be there in application.

**issue** :
Here i am protecting the routes using Auth guards so without logging, a user cannot access the page .If i sent the same page url to user via email he should be able to view only the page.

So my application has:

1. login page
2. products page
3. products-info page

Normally if a user logs in, this page will be visible but when an admin sends a url as *mobiledot.com/products-info*  to user's email, user clicks on that and application don't want to login and it doesn't want to show any logout or other pages info only on that specific page. below is my code :

*router.module.ts*

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'main/:role', component: MainComponent, canActivate: [RouteGuard] },
  { path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent},
  { path: 'user', component: userComponent,canActivate: [RouteGuard]}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [RouteGuard]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

auth guard

```
@Injectable()
export class RouteGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private service: accessService, private router: Router) {}

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean | Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> {
        const isAllowed = this.service.getAuthenticated();
        if (!isAllowed) {
            this.router.navigate(['/']);
        }
        return isAllowed;
    }

}
```

So i also thought about some thing like if user logs into application. My router module is:

```
if(user loginin){     
      { path: 'main/:role', component: MainComponent, canActivate: [RouteGuard] },    
    }
     else {
          { path: 'main/:token', component: MainComponent }, 
          ex:  www.mobiledot.com/product-info?toke="ssdsdsdsdSDSD"
}
```

Is it possible or do we have any other way?

In short, if admin sent the same page url in application which is protected by auth guards to the user via email then user will click on the link and open the page and it should not ask for login.

**There is another problem** which is about stored token in `localstorage`. so before moving, do we have to clear that token and place a new one so that it will not redirect to main page?

Comment: I think you should be able to check `history` for navigations. If it's the first entity in there this means that this was first navigation.

Comment: Can you share with us your products-info page route code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean that *products-info* should be visible for registered users, as they can receive the corresponding link inside their email while they may be unauthorized (perhaps by token expiration) so you need a solution to cover it.

First of all, **this is a bad practice** to reveal sth like `token` as Url parameter. So avoid it.

Second, Please try to employ right solution instead of changing basic behaviors in your App. `AuthGuard` designed to *decide if a route can be activated or not*. It uses browser storage and in case of token expiration, You can only refresh it **before expiration**, otherwise user has to login again.

**My solution** is creating sth like a ticket id which can be appended to the sent link (like `mobiledot.com/products-info/928f5f8b663571b7f3d829921c9079939c2d0319`). You can make it one-time valid or more for users. store it in database and validate it when a user uses. In this way, there's no need to employ `AuthGuard` just control content permission on server-side.

Answer (score 0):

As you have a route guard , you need a case where it's should return true even you are not logged in.

So, simply you can use the approach you have think of **[www.mobiledot.com/product-info?toke="ssdsdsdsdSDSD"](http://www.mobiledot.com/product-info?toke=%22ssdsdsdsdSDSD%22)**.

```
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean | Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> {
// check if there is a query param , like token in the url  and url is your without token one. 
           if(queryParamToken && urlpath === 'view'){
// as you have token hit the api to check if required to check token is a valid one.
or can simply return true as per your need / requirement


 -- checkout this link if you need referece
         } else {

            const isAllowed = this.service.getAuthenticated();
            if (!isAllowed) {
                this.router.navigate(['/']);
            }
            return isAllowed;
  }
        }
```

[Verify token with API in Angular8 canActivate method of AuthGuard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59442021/verify-token-with-api-in-angular8-canactivate-method-of-authguard)  -- checkout this link if you need reference